# Xcode 8 Segmentation Failure with Swift Class using GCDWebServer

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8, gcdwebserver

After upgrading to Xcode 8 I get a segmentation 11 error in the following class:

```
class WebServer: GCDWebServer
{
    static let sharedInstance = WebServer()
    var webServer = GCDWebServer()!

    override init()
    {
        GCDWebServer.setLogLevel(5) // comment out line for debug purposes
        self.webServer.addGETHandler(forBasePath: "/", directoryPath: "/", indexFilename: "", cacheAge: 0, allowRangeRequests: true)
        self.webServer.start(withPort: 8080, bonjourName: "GCD Web Server")
    }

    func getURLForPage(_ pageName:String)->URL
    {
        let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: pageName, withExtension: "html")
        let filePath = String(validatingUTF8: fileUrl!.path)!
        let webURLStr = "http://127.0.0.1:8080" + filePath

        return URL(string: webURLStr)!
    }
}
```

The log is pointing to the init but through commenting items out I can see that it's related to using the Objective C class GCDWebServer.  The specific log error is:

```
While emitting IR SIL function @_TFC4Book9WebServercfT_S0_ for 'init' at
```

It then points to the init method above.  Again all of this worked fine prior to upgrading to Xcode 8.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the deep sense of the line `var webServer = GCDWebServer()!` when using a shared instance?

Comment: You are correct that it isn't necessary over "sharedInstance".  It was a hold over I neglected to remove.  However, it also has no bearing on the issue with the segmentation fault.

Comment: Try enabling address sanitizer when running your app. Also provide the full stack trace of the crash as it may contain valuable info.